# Is frictional heat just electromagnetic interactions creating infrared radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

**Example:** Rub your index finger on a sheet of paper and you will feel that it will get noticeably hotter

Is the reason you feel this increase in heat (technically an increase in kinetic energy of the particles within the sheet of paper), as a result of the electromagnetic repulsion between the atoms on the tips of your finger and the atoms on the sheet of paper, generating/adding motion to the atoms within the paper and your finger?

*Sub Question:*

As a sub-question, the "heat" we feel daily from the sun is infrared radation. Could it be that the heat we feel on our index finger in the example above also be as a result of infrared radiation generated as a result of the electromagnetic interactions between the atoms in our index finger and the atoms in the sheet of paper?

Comment: Is it "just" electromagnetic repulsion? No, it's not "just" electromagnetic repulsion. The chemical stability of atoms and molecules depends on electrons being fermions and the resulting selection rules for atomic and molecular orbitals. In contrast, purely bosonic matter is usually believed to be unstable if I am not mistaken.